# Angular build with --aot fails with 'ɵbl' (imported as 'i1') was not found

Tags: build, angular-cli, angular8, aot

My Angular 8 application works just fine with `ng serve`.

However, with `ng build --prod --aot=true`, I get the following error during compilation :

```
"export 'ɵbl' (imported as 'i1') was not found in 'my-library'
```

It seems like there's a bug with with the `--aot` flag, as it successfully compiles without it.

How can I find what is wrong with `my-library` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building with `--aot`, these errors can show up when the library is not statically analyzable for AoT.

There are [some gotchas](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5) that you can check in `my-library` to make sure it is compliant with AoT.

However this might not be the case as your error is very much opaque : try adding the `--optimization=false` flag to disable compression and hopefully get more details about the error :

```
ng build --prod --aot=true --optimization=false
```

Your error message could then become clearer.